# Laravel 5.4 - Can't login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using the default laravel 5.4 login and i can't login because my password is always reject by laravel, however it's the good password that i gave.

It's working on the second try, the first time nothing happend, the id are just reset and when i retry it's working ( I triple checked it's not because i badly write the password )...

My passwords in my database are all hash like this :

`$2y$10$MOhxmMBPTlWK2Bk1MorY5OrjDlvudkFLqgICJHY1OlWX2MtoLwIwW`

I tried to understand how the login method work but it's too complicated, i can't find where the password is hash.

If you need to see some code, you can ask me but i didn't touch anything in the laravel login (just the login view).

Thanks you !

Comment: IF you're using the default auth scaffolding just click forgot password and set a new one?

Comment: I imagine this is likely user error

Comment: `php artisan tinker` and `Hash::make('yourPassword')` then replace the string in your db

Comment: Check you have already generated a key. also share how you are checking password.

Comment: Go to Auth folder in controller to understand authentication

Comment: If you happened to run `php artisan key:generate` after you created your passwords then **all your passwords will be un-usable**

Comment: It's because on the first try of my login nothing happend but it's working only on the second, i don't understand why ?

Comment: Like I say, likely user error

Comment: I check many times and the id are correct